# How to check conformance to protocol with associated type in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, associated-types

When I want to check if a type conforms to a simple protocol, I can use:

```
if let type = ValueType.self as? Codable.Type {}
```

When the protocol has associated type, for example `RawRepresentable` has `RawValue`, when I do:

```
if let type = ValueType.self as? RawRepresentable.Type {}
```

Compiler will show the following error:

> Protocol 'RawRepresentable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

So how to check conformance to protocol with associated type?

Comment: Common sense... What is `RawValue` in your case of `ValueType`? :)

Comment: This kind of check smells quite *objective-c-ish*. In a strong type language like Swift the type should be checked at compile time.

Comment: @DominikBucher I suppose it can be any type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR**
Compiler does not have *enough* information to compare the type **until associated type is set**.

---

When you refer to simple protocol, compiler knows its type from the beginning.
But when you refer to protocol with *associated type*, compiler doesn't know its type until you declare it.

```
protocol ExampleProtocol {
    associatedtype SomeType
    func foo(param: SomeType)
}
```

At this moment for compiler it looks like this:

```
protocol ExampleProtocol {
    func foo(param: <I don't know it, so I'll wait until it's defined>)
}
```

When you declare a class conforming to the protocol

```
class A: ExampleProtocol {
    typealias SomeType = String
    func foo(param: SomeType) {

    }
}
```

Compiler starts to see it like this:

```
protocol ExampleProtocol {
    func foo(param: String)
}
```

And **then** it is able to compare types.

Comment: In SwiftUI, how do we check if `Color` is a `View`? Could you show me how to do that in Swift? Thanks.

Comment: @lochiwei, A Color is a late-binding token: SwiftUI only resolves it to a concrete value just before using it in a given environment.

Comment: OK then, how do we check if a `Rectangle` is a `View`?

Comment: @lochiwei, Rectangle is a shape inside the view.

Comment: I mean `Rectangle` conforms to `InsettableShape`, `InsettableShape` inherits from `Shape`, and `Shape` inherits from `View`, so how do we check in code that a `Rectangle` is-a `View`?

Comment: @lochiwei is not inheritance since it's all structs not classes, better term would be "conforms"

Comment: @txaidw is there a way to write a test which will check if Rectangle conforms to View protocol?